# Who is better for a low computer Ubuntu or others like xubuntu or lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu

Ubuntu, Lubuntu, xubuntu, Kubuntu who of this is better for a low PC with only 1 GB ram and who have better programs and games and personalizations.

Comment: Lubuntu is the lightest.

Comment: and about the games and programs or have the same

Comment: It is same regarding applications.

Comment: You can install any game, irrespective of which Ubuntu flavor you use as a base. But games often require more memory, so you should probably consider a new pc.

Comment: hey guys how do i repair my pc because when i was installing ubuntu dual bot with windows 7the installation through the demo on live-usb were interrumpted and now im mising 22 gb

Answer (score -1):

Try [Bunsenlabs](https://www.bunsenlabs.org), Openbox on Debian.

Or [Cub Linux](http://cublinux.com), Openbox on Ubuntu 14.04, which I'm using right now, fast and beautiful.